# Texture array in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

```
fragment half4 fragmen_shader_test(WaterColorCloudOut params[[stage_in]],
                                                         texture2d<float , access::sample>cloud1 [[texture(0)]],
                                                         texture2d<half, access::sample> cloud2 [[texture(1)]],
                                                         texture2d<half, access::sample> cloud3 [[texture(2)]]
                                                         )
{
    constexpr sampler defaultSampler;
    float4 color1;

    if(params.index == 0){
        color1= float4(cloud1.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates)))  * params.color ;
    }
    else if(params.index == 1){
        color1= float4(cloud2.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates)))  * params.color ;
    } else{
        color1= float4(cloud3.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates)))  * params.color ;
    }

 return half4(color1);
}
```

Here I am using three textures  because of If-else condition the performance drops with time. I feel if i send a texture array to the shader there is no need to perform if else statement. In CPU I have three MTLTexture. How can I bind the three texture to an array and pass it shader.

In CPU side I created three Textures and Created a MTLTexture array

```
 var textureArray:[MTLTexture] = []
```

Then I append the Texture to that array.
In MTLRenderCommandEncoder

```
let myRange: CountableRange = 0..<2
commandEncoder.setFragmentTextures(textureArray, range: myRange)
```

In Shader

```
texture2d_array<float ,  access::sample> texture [[ texture(0) ]]
```

While sampling in Shader

```
float4 color = texture.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates),0) * float4(1,0,0,1.0);
```

I am doing like this currently ButI couldn't get the correct Texture output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to change the app code. Since you are using consecutive texture indexes, you can just replace the three separate parameters with a single texture array parameter bound to index 0 and the bindings will connect the elements of the array with the textures you've provided from the app code.

In other words, if you declare a texture array with size 3 and bound to texture index 0, the elements of the array are taken from texture index 0, 1, and 2.

---

Update for your edited question:

You are confusing an array **of** textures (also called a texture array) and an array texture. The terminology is confusingly subtle.

- An array texture is a single texture with multiple 2D planes in it. All of the planes have the same size and pixel format. The number of planes in the texture does not have to be known at shader compile time.
- An array of textures is an array of independent textures, which may have different sizes or pixel formats. The length of the array is a compile-time constant.

You used `texture2d_array<...>`. That's an array texture.

For a texture array, or array of textures, you should use `array<texture2d<float, access::sample>, 3> clouds [[texture(0)]]`.

To sample from a texture within the array, you first index into the array and then call a texture function on that element:

```
float4 color = clouds[params.index].sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates)) * float4(1,0,0,1.0);
```

Comment: I edited the question. I tried in above way. But I couldnt get the correct texture to the screen and It is blinking... Earlier I without array IT worked fine... What went wrong...

Comment: You'll have to test to find out. I think using an array of textures should be at least as fast as your manual switching code.